# Error pushing data in an Azure Function to an Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I'm consuming data from an Azure Service Bus and I want to push it to an Azure Event Hub.

I've created a function like so:

```
[FunctionName("IntegrationFunction")]
[return: EventHub("%Transactions:EVH:Transactions:Hub%", Connection = "Transactions:SB:Transactions")]
public Transaction Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(
        "%Transactions:SB:Transactions:ReceiveTopic%",
        "%Transactions:SB:Transactions:AnalyticsTopicSubscription%",
        Connection = "Transactions:SB:Transactions")]
    string mySbMsg,
    ILogger log)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mySbMsg))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mySbMsg));
    }

    log.LogInformation($"Service bus topic trigger function processing message: {mySbMsg}");
    
    var retailTransaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetailTransaction>(
        mySbMsg,
        JsonSerialisationUtils.SerialiserSettings);
    
    if (retailTransaction == null)
    {
        throw new JsonException("Deserialized transaction was null");
    }

    try
    {
        var transaction = retailTransaction.ToDto();
        log.LogInformation($"Transaction {transaction.TransactionNumber} processed.");
        return transaction;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.LogError(e, "Error mapping transaction.");
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, when the function is invoked, I receive the following error:

```
Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://****.servicebus.windows.net/Transactions-EVH-INS-DEV-EUW' could not be found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. TrackingId:**************, SystemTracker:****:Transactions-EVH-INS-DEV-EUW, Timestamp:2024-03-12T07:49:07.
```

Does that mean that the value of `%Transactions:EVH:Transactions:Hub%` is incorrect or something else? Why does the error mention service bus when I'm trying to publish to an event hub?

I've already read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

Comment: Did you try using eventhub output binding

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya Yes - my function is in the original post i.e. [return: EventHub("%Transactions:EVH:Transactions:Hub%", Connection = "Transactions:SB:Transactions")] ?

Comment: error `404` throws when the resource is not found check the  output`%Transactions:SB:Transactions:ReceiveTopic%` or `%Transactions:SB:Transactions:AnalyticsTopicSubscription%` or `Transactions:SB:Transactions` is same as the servicebus values you are consuming from

Comment: %Transactions:SB:Transactions:AnalyticsTopicSubscription% is the service bus I'm consuming from. Transactions:SB:Transactions is the shared connection. %Transactions:SB:Transactions:ReceiveTopic% is the event hub I'm trying to publish to.

Comment: for service bus trigger syntax is this [image](https://i.imgur.com/btnloiu.png). topic , subs, connection. it should be like this.

Comment: if you are mentioniong the receiving eventhub name in the place of service bus topic name which is resulting the error.

Comment: That image link doesn't work and I don't believe I am as shown in my code snippet. What specifically in my code snippet do you believe is incorrect?

Comment: as you mentioned `%Transactions:SB:Transactions:ReceiveTopic%` is the name value of the evenhub to which you want to send the message to. But as per syntace at that place you need to use the servicebus topic namey.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257144/discussion-between-vivek-vaibhav-shandilya-and-bhav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also getting the same error when I am trying to use the receiving  `eventhub name` in place of `topic name`.

[image]

[image]

Use correct syntax.

This worked for me.

##### My Code:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp12
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        [return: EventHub("receive",Connection ="hubconn")]
        public static string Run([ServiceBusTrigger("subtopic", "testsub", Connection = "conn")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
            return mySbMsg;
       
        }
    }
}
```

### `INPUT`:

```
Hello Vivek
```

[image]

### `OUTPUT`:

[image]

[image]